# VSCode not opening new window at launch and without extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

Upon launching VSCode I would like it to automatically open a new blank PowerShell file (.ps1).
I have settings.json configured the following way:

```
  "powershell.powerShellDefaultVersion": "Windows PowerShell (x86)",
  "workbench.editor.untitled.hint": "hidden",
  "interactiveWindow.restore": true,
  "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile"
```

Unfortunately, VSCode does not launch a new file upon program start and creating a new window with STRG+N does not create a file in .ps1. What am I missing?

Comment: The "new file" you are creating is just created in memory. To get formatting and everything, you either have to save that file (as *.ps1) or select the language in the bottom right corner (should say "Plain Text" by default). You can probably set `files.defaultLanguage` to `powershell`.

Comment: Thanks. STRG+N now creates a new .ps1 file. However, launching VSCode does not launch a new untitled file, no matter the extension. I have another VSCode installation on another machine and here it works to create a new file automatically. I use settings sync so settings.json is identical across installations.

Comment: Are you sure `workbench.startupEditor` is set on the machine where it's not working? Also, I would recommend setting `"window.restoreWindows": "none"`, because otherwise your previous instance will be restored, ignoring the startup editor setting.

Comment: Working now. Reinstalled the PowerShell extension. Thanks for your help.